# How do I import an image?

Tags: python, import, directory, pygame

I'm tying to import this image for a game but I can't access it.

```
YELLOW_SPACESHIP_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(
    os.path.join('Assets', 'spaceship_yellow.png'))
```

I imported `os` and `pygame`. I have this `'Assets'` file in the same directory as all my other python stuff, but it's saying I don't have `pygame`.

```
'/Users/carsonquinn/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/pythonProject/practice/PyGame' does not exist
```

This is the error I get even though I've checked that `pygame` is installed and I'm running the new version of python.

Comment: You have to install pygame on pip, or whatever other package manager of python : `python3 -m pip install -U pygame --user`

Comment: Note that the error message says you don't have `PyGame`, not `pygame` — perhaps that's a clue…

Comment: It looks like Pycharm cannot find the python script, not the library. Make sure to double-check your python interpreter settings in pycharm and set the script path to your python file.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: you didn't show full error message and code which make this problem - so we can't say what is the real problem. Maybe problem is different then you expect. I don't understand why you have two `pythonProject` in your path `... /pythonProject/pythonProject/ ...`

Comment: BTW: sometimes code may run in different folder then you expect and it is better to create full path to folder with your code `BASE = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` and later create full path `os.path.join(BASE, 'Assets', 'spaceship_yellow.png')`

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough to put the image files in the same directory or sub directory. You also need to set the working directory.
The image file path has to be relative to the current working directory. The working directory is possibly different to the directory of the python script. Copy the following at the beginning of your code to set the working directory to the same as the script's directory:

```py
import os
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```